# How to connect LD player in vs code?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-emulator, flutter-web

I installed the LD player in windows and VS code device is not detecting the LD player.
Note: I already changed ADB Debugging settings in LD Player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just restarted LD player and VS code, now it's working perfectly.